# Setting color with thresholds in bash (snmpget)

Tags: bash, colors, snmp

I have a bash script that allows me to get the electrical loads (between 0% and 100%) thanks to the "snmpget" command.

I would like to improve the script, by putting colour when the electric charge reaches 76% (yellow and bold) and when the electric charge reaches 90% (red and bold).

Example below:

```
for ((;;)); do
DATE=`date +"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"`
# OND1
  OND1L1=$(snmpget -v2c -c public -m SNMPv2-SMI $OND1 iso.3.6.1.2.1.33.[..].1 | cut -d\  -f 4)
  OND1L2=$(snmpget -v2c -c public -m SNMPv2-SMI $OND1 iso.3.6.1.2.1.33.[..].2 | cut -d\  -f 4)
  OND1L3=$(snmpget -v2c -c public -m SNMPv2-SMI $OND1 iso.3.6.1.2.1.33.[..].3 | cut -d\  -f 4)

# OND2
  OND2L1=$(snmpget -v2c -c public -m SNMPv2-SMI $OND2 iso.3.6.1.2.1.33.[..].1 | cut -d\  -f 4)
  OND2L2=$(snmpget -v2c -c public -m SNMPv2-SMI $OND2 iso.3.6.1.2.1.33.[..].2 | cut -d\  -f 4)
  OND2L3=$(snmpget -v2c -c public -m SNMPv2-SMI $OND2 iso.3.6.1.2.1.33.[..].3 | cut -d\  -f 4)
# OND3
  OND3L1=$(snmpget -v2c -c public -m SNMPv2-SMI $OND3 iso.3.6.1.2.1.33.[..].1 | cut -d\  -f 4)
  OND3L2=$(snmpget -v2c -c public -m SNMPv2-SMI $OND3 iso.3.6.1.2.1.33.[..].2 | cut -d\  -f 4)
  OND3L3=$(snmpget -v2c -c public -m SNMPv2-SMI $OND3 iso.3.6.1.2.1.33.[..].3 | cut -d\  -f 4)

 
  echo "Date: $DATE"
  echo "========================="
  echo "$OND1 Phases ==> L1: $OND1L1% L2: $OND1L2% L3: $OND1L3%"
  echo "---------------------------------------------------"
  echo "$OND2 Phases ==> L1: $OND2L1% L2: $OND2L2% L3: $OND2L3%"
  echo "---------------------------------------------------"
  echo "$OND3 Phases ==> L1: $OND3L1% L2: $OND3L2% L3: $OND3L3%"
  echo "---------------------------------------------------"
if [ $BrutMode == 1 ]; then
      echo "$DATE $OND1L1 $OND1L2 $OND1L3 $OND2L1 $OND2L2 $OND2L3 $OND3L1 $OND3L2 $OND3L3" | awk '{printf " %s  %s   %4.1f   %4.1f   %4.1f    %4.1f   %4.1f   %4.1f    %4.1f   %4.1f   %4.1f\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11}'
    else
      echo "$DATE $OND1L1 $OND1L2 $OND1L3 $OND2L1 $OND2L2 $OND2L3 $OND3L1 $OND3L2 $OND3L3" | awk '{printf " %s  %s   %4.1f%%  %4.1f%%  %4.1f%%   %4.1f%%  %4.1f%%  %4.1f%%   %4.1f%%  %4.1f%%  %4.1f%%\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11}'
    fi
    if [ $Repetition == 0 ]; then
      exit 0
    fi
    sleep $Delay
  done
  exit 0
fi
```

I don't see how to do it at all. I have already defined the colours and the type of font:

```
BRed="\[\033[1;31m\]" (Bold Red)
BYellow="\[\033[1;33m\]" (Bold Yellow)
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Have you also already defined a sequence for switching back to normal color?

Comment: The `\[` `\]` in your defined sequences look strange; are you sure they're right?

Answer (score 0):

Your color constants are wrong, you need to end the coloring, and you need to test each parameter alone while staying on the same line in the echos; something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

BRed="\033[1;31m"
BYel="\033[1;33m"
EndColoring="\033[0m"

OND1="theOND1"
OND1L1=75
OND1L2=76
OND1L3=90

if [ $OND1L1 -lt 76 ]
then
  echo -n "$OND1 Phases ==> L1: $OND1L1% L2: "
elif [ $OND1L1 -lt 90 ]
then
  echo -ne "$OND1 Phases ==> L1: $BYel$OND1L1%$EndColoring L2: "
else
  echo -ne "$OND1 Phases ==> L1: $BRed$OND1L1%$EndColoring L2: "
fi

if [ $OND1L2 -lt 76 ]
then
  echo -n "$OND1L2% L3: "
elif [ $OND1L2 -lt 90 ]
then
  echo -ne "$BYel$OND1L2%$EndColoring L3: "
else
  echo -ne "$BRed$OND1L2%$EndColoring L3: "
fi

if [ $OND1L3 -lt 76 ]
then
  echo "$OND1L3%"
elif [ $OND1L3 -lt 90 ]
then
  echo -e "$BYel$OND1L3%$EndColoring"
else
  echo -e "$BRed$OND1L3%$EndColoring"
fi
```